# What could be the solution to this Stripe and Wehook error?

Tags: stripe-payments

file:///Users/mac/Desktop/Sotofit/back-end/node_modules/stripe/esm/Error.js:7
return new StripeInvalidRequestError(rawStripeError);
^

StripeInvalidRequestError: Invalid val: [{"_id":"64e707601462c7a9b2c9a926","desc":"EWAGAHIN","image":"http://res.cloudinary.com/dmihhsps6/im...om/dmihhsps6/image/upload/v1692868880/Sotofit/ksfwjtyldzbbwa0ganle.png","price":"400","quantity":2}] must be a string under 500 characters
at Function.generate (file:///Users/mac/Desktop/Sotofit/back-end/node_modules/stripe/esm/Error.js:7:20)
at res.toJSON.then.StripeAPIError.message (file:///Users/mac/Desktop/Sotofit/back-end/node_modules/stripe/esm/RequestSender.js:102:43)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
type: 'StripeInvalidRequestError',
raw: {
message: 'Invalid val: [{"_id":"64e707601462c7a9b2c9a926","desc":"EWAGAHIN","image":"http://res.cloudinary.com/dmihhsps6/im...om/dmihhsps6/image/upload/v1692868880/Sotofit/ksfwjtyldzbbwa0ganle.png","price":"400","quantity":2}] must be a string under 500 characters',
param: 'metadata',
request_log_url: 'https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/req_FEDLmQMpIH89Fk?t=1694450970',
type: 'invalid_request_error',
headers: {
server: 'nginx',
date: 'Mon, 11 Sep 2023 16:49:30 GMT',
'content-type': 'application/json',
'content-length': '470',
connection: 'keep-alive',
'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
'access-control-expose-headers': 'Request-Id, Stripe-Manage-Version, X-Stripe-External-Auth-Required, X-Stripe-Privileged-Session-Required',
'access-control-max-age': '300',
'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store',
'idempotency-key': 'stripe-node-retry-e4f75476-47c4-4410-aed4-3a258fd29505',
'original-request': 'req_FEDLmQMpIH89Fk',
'request-id': 'req_FEDLmQMpIH89Fk',
'stripe-version': '2023-08-16',
vary: 'Origin',
'x-stripe-routing-context-priority-tier': 'api-testmode',
'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload'
},
statusCode: 400,
requestId: 'req_FEDLmQMpIH89Fk'
},
rawType: 'invalid_request_error',
code: undefined,
doc_url: undefined,
param: 'metadata',
detail: undefined,
headers: {
server: 'nginx',
date: 'Mon, 11 Sep 2023 16:49:30 GMT',
'content-type': 'application/json',
'content-length': '470',
connection: 'keep-alive',
'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
'access-control-expose-headers': 'Request-Id, Stripe-Manage-Version, X-Stripe-External-Auth-Required, X-Stripe-Privileged-Session-Required',
'access-control-max-age': '300',
'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store',
'idempotency-key': 'stripe-node-retry-e4f75476-47c4-4410-aed4-3a258fd29505',
'original-request': 'req_FEDLmQMpIH89Fk',
'request-id': 'req_FEDLmQMpIH89Fk',
'stripe-version': '2023-08-16',
vary: 'Origin',
'x-stripe-routing-context-priority-tier': 'api-testmode',
'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload'
},
requestId: 'req_FEDLmQMpIH89Fk',
statusCode: 400,
charge: undefined,
decline_code: undefined,
payment_intent: undefined,
payment_method: undefined,
payment_method_type: undefined,
setup_intent: undefined,
source: undefined
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

i was trying to get my cartItems to be use in my Webhook and it keep complaining of words more than 500 characters and that was the reason why i gave a condition statement above to handle it but if the customer buys more items it make the character more that 500 please how can i handle that

Comment: "if the customer buys more items it make the character more that 500" Then metadata is the wrong place to store this data. Store it in your database; put an ID for that record in the Stripe metadata instaed.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting happens during an API request you made to Stripe's API. You didn't share any code but bhe 500 characters limit is usually related to [metadata](https://stripe.com/docs/api/metadata) so I'm assuming you are passing an invalid value in the `metadata` parameter.

You need to fix your code to ensure you respect Stripe's limits around metadata usage and that you split your data into multiple keys if the value is too long. Alternatively, you can store this information in your own database and have a reference to that row/data in the metadata instead.

If you look at the error your get back, there's a direct link to the request log in the Dashboard https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/req_FEDLmQMpIH89Fk where you can see the exact API call you made, the parameters you passed, the response from Stripe and easily debug this on your own.
If you have more questions, you would likely have more luck with Stripe's own support team instead: https://support.stripe.com/contact

Also you likely want to read Stripe's doc around error handling in their API [here](https://stripe.com/docs/error-handling) and update your code to properly catch those.